# Electron App: jquery Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron, atom-editor

> Electron version: 1.0.0 
>   Operating system: Description: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Release: 12.04

There is a problem with `.hasClass()` function, I want to store all div element using `var div = $('div');` with this div object I want to get to play a video if its inside my `Encrypt` class, while on the same page I have the same video but I'll play when we are inside `Decrypt` class so function are same

```
function Pause() {
  if (div.hasClass('Encrypt')) {
    myvideo1.pause();
  } else {
    myvideo2.pause();
  }
}
```

same source video but with different id in variable myvideo1 and myvideo2

but I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined

Comment: Looks like there is some issue with the `div` selector. Try logging the `div` variable in the console to check its value